# gem install ruby-debug-ide failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi all I'm using ruby ruby 2.5.1 and Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3

Below is the terminal output:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Stephen:~ stephenlang$ gem install ruby-debug-ide
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:

    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1/ext
/Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
Installing base gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/debase-0.2.3.beta5/ext
/Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190303-47502-1m85nrg.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ruby-dir
    --without-ruby-dir
    --with-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
    --with-ruby-lib
    --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:590:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1097:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:947:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:946:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1096:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:31:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.10.4/lib/debase/ruby_core_source.rb:15:in `create_makefile_with_core'
    from extconf.rb:53:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.5.0-static/debase-0.2.3.beta5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/debase-0.2.3.beta5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.5.0-static/debase-0.2.3.beta5/gem_make.out
/Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:92:in `run'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:46:in `block in build'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tempfile.rb:295:in `open'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:30:in `build'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:164:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:163:in `chdir'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:163:in `block in build_extension'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:162:in `synchronize'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:162:in `build_extension'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `block in build_extensions'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `each'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/installer.rb:774:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/installer.rb:306:in `install'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:97:in `install'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:168:in `block in install'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `each'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `install'
  /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:409:in `install'
  mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in <main>'
  mkrf_conf.rb:28:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/stephenlang/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.5.0-static/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1/gem_make.out
```

Any ideas as to why this is failing?

Comment: what does mkmf.log say?

Comment: Read your error message: “You have to install development tools first.”

Answer (score 2):

On mac you'll need to install Xcode

```
xcode-select --install
```

If that fails, [go here and install Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) first then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error even though I already had Xcode installed. Solution was to open Xcode and agree to latest terms & conditions + allow it to run through some component updates; afterwards `gem install ruby-debug-ide` worked.